# How to return a string via interface{}

Tags: go

I have the following function.  I want to return the *string via the object interface{} parameter. If json.Unmarshal fails

I tried a bunch of variations but still it's coming out blank from the calling function.  Although the type showing on the outside for the object is "string*", although it's empty.  How can I do this?

My actual code below.  But, for simplicity here an even simpler version.
https://go.dev/play/p/nnsKZxvU42M

```
// UnmarshalObject decodes an object from binary data
func UnmarshalObject(data []byte, object interface{}) error {
    err := json.Unmarshal(data, object)
    if err != nil {
        s := string(data)
        object = &s
    }

    return nil
}
```

It's being called like this

```
func (connection *DbConnection) GetObject(bucketName string, key []byte, object interface{}) error {
// ...

    err = UnmarshalObject(data, object)

    return err

}
```

From this function

```
// DBVersion retrieves the stored database version.
func (service *Service) DBVersion() (int, error) {
    var version string
    err := service.connection.GetObject(BucketName, []byte(versionKey), &version)
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }
    return strconv.Atoi(version)
}
```

In this case, Atoi fails because version is ""

Comment: If `object` is a `*string` then unmarshaling is always going to fail. If it’s not a string pointer, then you can’t set a string value to that pointer.

Comment: @JimB sorry a bit more context added.  It's actually a string pointer as version string.

Comment: Can you log the value of `versionKey` e.g. `log.Printf("%q", string(versionKey))` to see the JSON & just in case there's some rogue bytes in there.

Comment: Thanks Cerise, I was actually running delve to verify all this

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out and learned something along the way.  This form works.

```
   // UnmarshalObject decodes an object from binary data
func UnmarshalObject(data []byte, object interface{}) error {
    err := json.Unmarshal(data, object)
    if err != nil {
       if s, ok := object.(*string); !ok {
            return err
       }

       *s = string(data)
    }

    return nil
}
```

Comment: You're checking the type of `object` but using `data`.

Comment: Correct. What were you expecting? In this code, the data being passed in is either a JSON string or a string and nothing else.  The type of object is what is expected - a string in this case.  So I simply assign the data to it as is.

Comment: You have a string that might be JSON. If it is, great. If not, and the caller expects a string, pass through the original string. Else return an error. Got it. That's a lot clearer than your question.

Comment: Thanks. Sometimes hard to write a clear question.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, use a [type-switch](https://golangdocs.com/type-switches-in-golang) to check if the interface is any of your expected types.

```
func UnmarshalObject(data []byte, object interface{}) error {
    err := json.Unmarshal(data, object)
    if err {
        return error;
    }

    switch object.(type) {
        case string:
            // object is a string
        case int:
            // object is an integer
        default:
            // object is something you did not expect.
            return fmt.Errorf("Unknown type %T", v)
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Comment: This would not do what I want.   I want the data (always a string of some sort) in the call, to be returned if json.Unmarshal fails.  Not all the strings are json.  It's coming from boltdb.

Comment: Simplified version:  https://go.dev/play/p/nnsKZxvU42M